# Batch bash installer script for clean Ubuntu GNOME installation

Tags: bash, linux, installer

I just finished (I think) writing a bash script to install all my essential software to Ubuntu GNOME. I'll be making more for different distributions but once I have one to go off of, I can do the rest fine.

I am very new to it all, however, and have ***barely*** gotten into using the cli so I'm sure that there are a ton of errors below. If you could just read through it and let me know what I can fix/improve, that would be wonderful! This is meant to run a *nearly* clean install; I'll have to open Firefox and download two files; the script and the extensions list. Other than that, everything is still set to default.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y gnome-tweak-tool 
sudo apt-get install -y variety
sudo apt-get install -y hunspell-en-gb
sudo apt-get install -y gdebi 
sudo apt-get install -y gparted 
sudo apt-get install -y libreoffice-style-breeze
sudo apt-get install -y evolution
sudo apt-get install -y evolution-indicator
sudo apt-get install -y cairo-dock
cd
cd Downloads
mkdir Programs
cd Programs
wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
wget https://atom.io/download/deb
sudo dpkg -i atom*
sudo apt-get install -f
wget https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/vnc.files/VNC-Server-6.2.0-Linux-x64.deb
sudo dpkg -i VNC-Server*
sudo apt-get install -f
wget https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/viewer.files/VNC-Viewer-6.17.731-Linux-x64.deb
sudo dpkg -i VNC-Viewer*
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo cd /usr/share/icons
wget https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1464728434/164587-bridge.tar.gz
tar -xvzf 164587-bridge.tar.gz
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:papirus/papirus
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install papirus-icon-theme
sudo apt install numix-gtk-theme
xterm -e "echo Make sure you select Bridge as the cursor, Papirus as the icon theme, and Numix as the GTK+ theme && gnome-tweak-tool"
cd
xterm -e "echo Replace whatever is there with Bridge && sudo gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key FDC247B7
echo 'deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/windscribe-repo.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install windscribe-cli
xterm windscribe login && windscribe start && echo Connect to Windscribe with windscribe connect best
echo All thats left is to do is, if youre using GNOME, enable all of your chosen extensions at extensions.gnome.org
cd
echo Use gedit /Documents/Scripts/Extension_Links to view my links to GNOME Shell Extensions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Wall of code

The script looks like a *wall of code*.
It would be a lot more pleasant to read if related groups of commands were separated from each other by blank lines, for example:

```
# install steam
wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

# install atom
wget https://atom.io/download/deb
sudo dpkg -i atom*
sudo apt-get install -f
```

#### Displaying info

This is not a very user-friendly (or pretty) way to show a message to the user before opening `gnome-tweak-tool`:

> ```
> xterm -e "echo Make sure you select Bridge as the cursor, Papirus as the icon theme, and Numix as the GTK+ theme && gnome-tweak-tool"
> ```

Since you are on a Gnome Desktop, you can benefit from `zenity`,
a scriptable tool to display dialogs, for example like this:

```
zenity --info --text="Make sure you select Bridge as the cursor, Papirus as the icon theme, and Numix as the GTK+ theme" && gnome-tweak-tool
```

#### Pointless command

This command will have no useful effect:

> ```
> sudo cd /usr/share/icons
> ```

In fact, instead of this:

> ```
> sudo cd /usr/share/icons
> wget https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1464728434/164587-bridge.tar.gz
> tar -xvzf 164587-bridge.tar.gz
> ```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
wget -O /tmp/bridge.tar.gz https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1464728434/164587-bridge.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvzf /tmp/bridge.tar.gz -C /usr/share/icons
```

That is, download the tarball to a temporary folder,
and extract the content with `root` into `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: The command at the bottom is to put the cursor theme Bridge in the Icon folder so it shows up in the Tweak Tool. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Amolith I thought you might expect that, but that's not will actually happen. The `164587-bridge.tar.gz` file will be extracted in the folder where the current user is, which is `~/Downloads/Programs` in your script

Comment: Since I'm extracting it after I've cd'd to that directory, wouldn't I be in that directory?

Comment: @Amolith `sudo cd /somepath` makes the `root` user `cd` to `/somepath`. The current user will not change its working directory. Only the `root` user will, and until the `sudo` shell ends. On the next `sudo` execution, the `root` user will be back in its home.

Comment: So would `sudo tar . . .` extract it in the correct directory or should I just download/extract it in some other directory and `sudo cp` it into `/usr/share/icons`?

Comment: @Amolith I rolled back your last update because it invalidates my answer. You should not update the code after you received answers.

Comment: I didn't think about that. I'm sorry. Did you see my other comment?

Comment: @Amolith I updated my answer with a possible solution to extracting the file into the correct directory

Comment: I edited that into the file and am about to execute it! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: It executed nearly flawlessly! Thank you so much!